# Curious of the shape of numpy.linspace

Tags: python, numpy

I have this NumPy array:

```
X = numpy.linspace(1, 10, 10)
```

I believe the output will become
`(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`

Why is the shape of this array `(10,)`? I don't understand why it isn't `(1,10)`.

Comment: Why did you expect (1,10)?  `np.array([1,2,3])` produces a (3,), not (1,3).  Same with `arange`.  Why should `linspace` be any different?  Is there something in the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you created a vector, and vectors are always in a single dimension.
If you want to have shape, (1,10) you can specifiy the shape using `X.reshape((1,10))`